# twilio - can I restrict trunking to particular pots numbers?

Tags: twilio

I am developing an asterisk dialplan which uses twilio to dial to staff contact numbers. Is there any way in twilio to whitelist or restrict access to particular numbers only?

I considered this question appropriate since twilio's own help documentation directs questions to this site and hackers could potentially use twilio's REST interface to make calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Twilio does not make available any way to whitelist numbers (you can [whitelist countries that your numbers can call in your international permissions section in your console](https://www.twilio.com/console/voice/settings/geo-permissions)). If you want to make specific number restrictions, you'll need to do it on your side.